# Netsuite System Notes for Contract Items

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite, I am trying to create a Saved Search report that shows field changes to individual contract line items. I will be using this report to reconstruct historical data, including pricing and quantities.

I have a Transaction Saved Search that shows me each contract and every contract line item. I have tried to include System Notes fields to pull in the field history, but it is only able to show me System Notes for the overall contract record (not the individual line items).

I also tried creating a System Notes Saved Search, which pulled the details I was looking for, but does not show me the Internal ID of the record (it shows me the "Record", which appears as a string - ex: "Contract #12345"). It also does not show me the ID of the contract line item, so even if I am able to join based on the Contract ID, I don't know which line items were affected.

If I navigate to the contract in NetSuite and look at the Items list, I am able to click the "History" button to see a list of changes - this is the information I am trying to pull. Is there any way to do this through a Saved Search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction item sublist history, is not yet exposed on the saved search/suitescript.

There might be an enhancement request for this use case.